# Why does my cat /etc/fstab look so odd? Is there a way to format the output?

Tags: command-line, fstab

When I run `cat /etc/fstab` I see this:

[image: /etc/fstab output screenshot]

I get the impression that the output isn't formatted correctly as a table should be. My terminal is full screen and so I don't think "wrapping" is to blame.

Other commands such as `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo parted -l` appear well-formatted on screen with data in nice columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other commands you mentioned may indeed display properly formatted data, but `cat` simply displays a file (in this case `/etc/fstab`), and if the file is not nicely formatted, `cat` won't make it prettier.

If you care about this, you might use an editor and align the columns manually in `/etc/fstab`, say `sudo nano /etc/fstab`. Be careful though to not mess up the file.

Comment: `cat` has a few options and `cat -E` shows a `$` at the end of each line which makes the output a little more comprehensible if not prettier.

Answer (score 3):

Basically there's no "format" for this file. Have a look at the "headers" :

```
<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
```

There's literally not enough space to write the file system if you want to stay in the "column". Given the fact that your `/etc/fstab` contains file systems UUID, it's even more impossible.

Of course, you're free to "reformat" the file, using `nano` for instance. If you just add tabs and spaces, there's very little risk that you'll corrupt the file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the output of `cat /etc/fstab` command is more odd than yours:

[image: cat /etc/fstab]

Now, I suggest you to not edit and reformat `/etc/fstab`. If some changes will appear in your file system, the file will be overwritten and so your edits will be in vain. You can use a small simple shell script like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo "---------------------------------------------------------"
cat /etc/fstab | 
awk '{ 
    if ($1 != "#") 
    print "File System:\t"$1"\nMount Point:\t"$2"\nType:\t\t"$3"\nOptions:\t" \
           $4"\nDump:\t\t"$5"\nPass:\t\t"$6"\n---------------------------------------------------------"
}'
```

The result:

[image: fstab]

Comment: Your output is "more odd" but would look like mine if you increased the number of columns in the terminal.

Comment: @vesa As I told you: if you edit `/etc/fstab` you will not solve nothing. Soon or later, that file can be overwritten.

Comment: `man fstab` has this:  `fstab is only read by programs, and not written;  it is  the duty  of  the system administrator to properly create and maintain this file.` In any case, my question was limited to how the contents of `fstab` display on the screen by default. I'm not keen on editing it.